# MySQL substring when LIMIT

Tags: mysql

This query `select @@version limit 0,1` returns:

```
 5.6.30-1
```

And I can substring without LIMIT:

`select substring(@@version,1,1);`

which returns:

`5`

How can I achieve this¿?

```
select substring((@@version limit 0,1),1,1);
```

I want to be given `5` I need this to work for a case where many columns are present, but the query below returns an error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 0,1),1,1)' at line 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution:

`select 5 = substring(@@version,1,1) limit 0,1;`

or `select 'A' = substring(table_name,1,1) from information_schema.tables where table_schema=database () limit 0,1;`

and it works, just setting the `()` around the value to substring and putting outside everything else
;)

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` is for limiting the number of **rows** in the resulting set not for string manipulation. It seems like you looking for [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@@version, '.', 1) major;
```

Output

```
+-------+
| major |
+-------+
| 5     |
+-------+
```